# cURL couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I want to be able to test via my website if my stream is playing. So it will update itself accordingly.

I'm using PHP - cURL to read the file, but am getting a "couldn't connect to host" error.
the script works with other URLs, just not this one.

Also the URL below works through the browser.

```
<?php
///if below doesn't work try this 86.28.144.85:88/broadwave.m3u?src=1&amp;rate=1///

$ch = curl_init("http://82.35.172.112:88/broadwave.m3u?src=p&rate=1");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

"couldn't connect to host" means exactly that. Most likely, a firewall is blocking connections to port 88.

Try moving your server to the standard HTTP port 80, or a high port such as 8080. You can use [balance](http://www.inlab.de/balance.html) to simply redirect everything on a port of your choosing to port 88.

Comment: He said "the script works with other url's", so I doubt that's the problem

Comment: Other URLs most likely use port 80, 443, or >1024. 88 is reserved for Kerberos, which is virtually always used in a local network, and therefore often firewalled.

Comment: Hi all thank's for the responses,if the url works as a normal link, can it still be blocked when trying to connect via php?

Comment: @Roy Yes, of course: your firewall may simply whitelist your browser, or your browser may be configured to use a proxy.